# Python web scraping span id using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a number data from a span id but the output I get is "--". The code works with no error messages but instead of printing a number like "58990" it will print "--". This website basically updates a number every 24h and I want my code to scrape every time this number is updated.

```
page = requests.get("https://covidtracker.fr/vaccintracker/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
home = soup.find(class_="page-template page-template-template_vaccintracker page-template-template_vaccintracker-php page page-id-3717")
posts = home.find_all(class_="wrap")



for post in posts:
    title = post.find(id="nb_doses_injectees_24h")
    print(title.text)
```

[image: website screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it would be better practise to use tag names in all your `soup` objects. Secondly, only `class` attribute can be called by `class_` in bs4. All other attributes should be passed as a dictionary.

`soup.find('<tag_name>', {'<attr_name>': '<attr_value>'})`

Unfortunately the website you are scraping is dynamic website which means you cannot scrape it by calling static elements with `bs4`. If you view page source and look for the tag you scrape you will see that:

```
<div class="wrap"> <div class="one"> <span id="nb_doses_injectees" style="font-size:200%; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 3px;">--</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;(+<span id="nb_doses_injectees_24h">--</span>
```

This is the reason why you are getting `--` as result. You need to swap to `selenium` to scrape `JS-based` websites. The below one would be working perfectly for your case:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://covidtracker.fr/vaccintracker/'
chrome_driver_path = 'chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Retrieve url in headless browser
    driver.get(url)
    
    data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nb_doses_injectees_24h"]').text
    # Result is data = "61 643"

    driver.close()
```